# Appcelerator Alloy how to include lib or component?

Tags: include, components, appcelerator, using, appcelerator-alloy

I would like to use TiRemoteImage from https://github.com/ulizama/TiRemoteImage
and in my alloy project I have added lib and components folder in app folder. Then I copy the files in TiRemoteImage's Resources/lib and Resources/components folder into my project's lib and components respectively
So my project folder structure looks like this now

```
app
> assets    
> components    
> controllers    
> lib    
> models
> styles
> views
```

I have then added

```
var RemoteImage = require('/components/remoteimage');
```

in `index.js` and then my app will just crash without any error. Am I including the component correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Alloy framework and the github project is not an alloy project so you have to copy all modules (.js in components and lib ) in /lib folder and change all line of code like : `require("/components/module.js")` ou `require("/lib/module.js")` by `require("module.js")`